# How do I get the response for CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm writing data to a characteristic with:

```
[peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

How do I get the response?

Comment: It should call `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:`.

Comment: It does, but the Bluetooth device is supposed to give me data based on what I sent it. How do I get that data?

Comment: You have to issue a read request or turn notify on for the characteristic to retrieve the value of the characteristic. `writeWithResponse` simply gives you a response to let you know that the write was successful (which you are getting)